# Calling a setInterval(); function inside a Java Script Class (OOP)

Tags: javascript, class, oop, setinterval

I am trying to call setInterval(); on a function inside a class but I am having problems instantiating it when it is within a class. Do I instantiate it in the constructor or somewhere in the class itself?
I call setInterval on the changePrice(); function yet checking the console for the test if its updating does not seem to work.

```
class Stocks {
  
  availableStocks = [{name: 'GOOG', price: 10, qty:3},
  
  availableFunds = 1000;
  cashflow = 1000;

constructor (name, price, qty) { 
  
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
  this.qty = qty;
  this.changePrice();
 }

changePrice (this.price) {

        //generate random number -1 or 1
        let chance = Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1;
    
        //adds chance/10 to price
        price += chance/10; 
        console.log(price);
        return price;
  }
setInterval(this.changePrice(), 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two reasons.

First, `this.changePrice()` calls the function immediately, and passes the return value to `setInterval`. You need to omit the parentheses, because you want to pass the function *itself* rather than call it immediately: `this.changePrice`.

Second, you will find that this is still not quite right, because `this` is a tricky thing. You are passing the function, but not the `this` parameter, so inside the callback, `this` will refer to the global `window` object. To solve that, you somehow need to *bind* `this` to the function. There are several techniques for this.

The classic:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function() { self.changePrice() }, 1000);
```

The slightly obscure:

```
setInterval(this.changePrice.bind(this), 1000);
```

The modern:

```
setInterval(() => this.changePrice(), 1000);
```

Comment: Great thanks! Super helpful I think this helps to solve my problem now. I am getting the hand of JS but where to call functions can be tricky, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Instanciate your class (you define it but don't actually create an instance
2. Launch the interval in the constructor. You can't have an instruction like `setInterval` floating like this in the middle of a Class, outside the constructor or a method.
3. Job done

```
    class Stocks {
    
        availableStocks = [{ name: 'GOOG', price: 10, qty: 3 }],
    
        availableFunds = 1000;
        cashflow = 1000;
    
        constructor(name, price, qty) {
    
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.qty = qty;
    
            this.changePrice();
            setInterval(this.changePrice, 1000);
        }
    
        changePrice(this.price) {
    
            //generate random number -1 or 1
            let chance = Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1;
    
            //adds chance/10 to price
            price += chance / 10;
            console.log(price);
            return price;
        }
    
    }
    
    new Stocks(); // Instanciate your class
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I should initiate it in the constructor or not this really helped clear things up.